# Adding a command-line tool in Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, toolchain

I'm trying to install [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), and i was wondering how i would add this into the toolchain? I would like to access this tool in the same way we use 'ls', 'vim', 'git', etc.

I've been searching google, however I can't find anything referring to the subject.

Comment: what do you mean by toolchain? Do you want Xcode to use it? If you just want to call it yourself, put it in your PATH.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I just wanted to use it in the terminal